# Salesforce: SOSL with CONTAINS

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-sosl

On salesforce i saw apps which are able to run CONTAINS queries. Even the basic list filter functionality on object list allows the CONTAINS filtering.

Using SOSL i tried the following:

```
List<List<SObject>> searchList = [FIND '*ben* AND *berlin*' IN ALL FIELDS 
                                  RETURNING Account(Name)];
```

I have an account name "BigBen" in "Berlin". I am not able to find this account using upper SOSL call. I tried different combinations, but no success. How do i do SOSL calls with CONTAINS?
Using the basic list filtering i am able to use CONTAINS with "ben", it gives me the expected results.

Comment: You can look this link it may be helpful https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_find.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike [SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_where.htm) which supports wildcards anywhere in the search term using the `LIKE` comparison operator, [SOSL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_find.htm) does *not* allow the use wildcards at the beginning of a search term (a "starts with" search).

In this case, where you are searching only one sObject, you might do better with SOQL.